# Ajax Upload fails with Ajax Push Engine (APE server) enabled

Tags: ajax, upload, comet, ajax-upload, cometserver

Whenever I disable the APE comet Server, AJAX file uploads run properly. And when enabled, the response.responseText from PHP is not parsed.

This problem has been bugging me since about more than a month.

There's another person here with the same problem: [Can not use ajax-upload because of ape comet server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012636/can-not-use-ajax-upload-because-of-ape-comet-server)

Can anyone please help us both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we found out the answer ourselves.. APE keeps making its own AJAX calls on a continuous basis, and it would conflict with my own uploading function.

To solve it, we used Valum's uploader, though I cant find a link to it now.